# Hot Module Replacement in a Meteor app with React and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, meteor, webpack, hot-module-replacement

I'm developing a web app in an environment consisting of Meteor, React, TypeScript and Webpack. Every time I make a change to a file I have to run webpack to recompile the full project and this can take a long time (20-30 seconds). Does anyone know if there is any way to recompile only the modified file (as the Webpack [Hot Module Replacement](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/) or the [React Hot Loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) module works) within a Meteor app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats the reason of using webpack with Meteor? Meteor builds the app in about 3 to 5 secs. Until now there is no official support for hmr on meteor.

Comment: The development environment was imposed to me at work. We were using Meteor and Blaze but somebody decided we must use React, TypeScript and Webpack now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It was as easy as using [Webpack Watch](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/). I created a script `dev` in `package.json` that runs `meteor & webpack` and added `watch: true` in `webpack.config.js` (it would be the same adding `--watch` in the script) so runing `npm run dev` starts in parallel Meteor and Webpack watching for file changes. When a file is changed, it recompiles in about just 2 seconds and refreshes the browser.